# Imprimir solo los dos primeros caracteres de una cadena en un array en lenguaje C

Tags: array, c

Soy nueva en el lenguaje C y tengo que crear un programa que registre a los usuarios pero que al momento de consultarlos no salga el nombre ingresado, solo sus dos primeros caracteres. Por ejemplo si el usuario se llama Paco al momento de consultar a los usuarios registrados solo se mostrara PA seguido por un numero consecutivo como PA001. Hay alguna manera de lograr esto?

```js
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct registro{
char nombre[100];
int opcion;


}personas[6];


int main(){
  int choice;
  int i;
do {
printf("Eliga una opcion:\n");
printf("1.Captura\n");
printf("2.Consulta\n");
printf("3.Salir");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 if (choice==1){
    printf("Captura\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
    printf("Escribe tu nombre:\n",i+1);
    gets(personas[i].nombre);

   printf("\n");

}

for(i=0;i<5;i++){

    printf("%i.Su nombre es:%s",i+1,personas[i].nombre);
    printf("\n");
}
 }

 if (choice==2){

    printf("Consulta\n");
for(i=0; i<5;i++){
    printf("%i.Su nombre es:%s",i+1,personas[i].nombre);
    printf("\n");
}
 }

 if (choice==3){
    printf("Salir");


 }
  }while(choice !=3);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas ... *para gustos, colores* :-)

1. Recorremos la cadena y mostramos 1 a 1 sus caracteres, hasta el número que nos interese.

   ```
   for( int idx = 0; idx < NUM_A_MOSTRAR; ++idx ) {
     printf( "%c", ARREGLO[idx] );
   ```
2. `printf( )` admite indicar **cuantos** caracteres queremos mostrar:

   ```
   printf( "%.2s", ARREGLO );
   ```

   Incluso podemos pasarle un argumento a `printf( )`, para que no sea un número *literal*:

   ```
   printf( "%.*s", NUM_A_MOSTRAR, ARREGLO );
   ```
3. Si nos sentimos especialmente trabajadores, y la cadena a mostrar no es constante, podemos colocar un *terminador* (el caracter `0`) *a mano* y restaurarlo después:

   ```
   char originalValue = ARREGLO[NUM_A_MOSTRAR];
   ARREGLO[NUM_A_MOSTRAR] = 0;
   printf( "%s", ARREGLO );
   ARREGLO[NUM_A_MOSTRAR] = originalValue;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer. Saludos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char palabra[20];
int cantLetras = 2; // Elijo la cantidad de letras que deseo saber.(Izq a derecha)

  dimeLetra(char text[]){

   char buffer[512]; // Buffer para copiar

   strncpy(buffer,text,cantLetras);

   printf("\rPrimeras 2 letras:\t%s",buffer); // Visualización de la cadena
}
int main()
{
    printf("Introduce tu palabra: ");
    scanf("%s",&palabra);

    dimeLetra(palabra);

   return 0;
}
```